# Add SSL support to docker container

Tags: svn, ssl, docker

I am working with an Go based application that is being run in a docker container using the docker-engine. In this container, I am looking to run subversion as part of the application. The issue I am running into is that svn is having issues accessing the repository due to SSL certificate issue. I already have a certificate file that I can use for the svn server I am trying to access and need to install that into the docker container so that the svn inside the container can use it.

Any advice on how to do this? Can I do this in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at "[SVN Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html)", you could specify which certificate SVN needs to trust with the property

```
ssl-authority-files
```

> This is a semicolon-delimited list of paths to files containing certificates of the certificate authorities (or CAs) that are accepted by the Subversion client when accessing the repository over HTTPS.

You would need to [`COPY` (in your Dockerfile)](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy):

- a certificate
- a system-wide configuration area (`/etc/subversion/servers`), or a per-user configuration area (`~/.subversion/servers`) with that property set to that certificate.

The global section of that servers file would look like:

```
[global]
ssl-authority-files=/etc/ssl/certs/example.pem
```

> If you need to trust several certificates then this can be done by placing them in a semicolon-separated list:

```
[global]
ssl-authority-files=/etc/ssl/certs/example.pem;/etc/ssl/certs/another-example.pem
```

Comment: Hmm... I am still running into issues.
I am getting this error message run trying to run the docker container:
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

Here is a snippet of my docker file:

`COPY /etc/ssl/certs/cert1.pem /etc/ssl/certs/cert1.pem
COPY /etc/ssl/certs/cert2.pem /etc/ssl/certs/cert2.pem
COPY /etc/subversion/servers /etc/subversion/servers`

Comment: @Andrew do a docker exec yourContainer bash, and see if SVN (as run in the container) has the right certificate. Follow for instance http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_subversion_to_trust_a_given_ssl_certificate.html

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like they were not being copied into the /etc directory of the docker root directory but instead into the docker containers context directory. Any idea on how to make the COPY go to the docker root directory?

Comment: @Andrew COPy will always copy in a docker context directory, not in your host /home/docker root directory. Having an image allowing containers with `/etc/ssl/certs/...` is good in your case.